# Search Paths of Visual Studio 2015 in Python 3.6 does not work to have a reference to lib

Tags: visual-studio-2015, python-3.6

I found it is wired that if I use Python 3.6 in vs2015, the search paths will be useless.  Python will show me "No module named 'xxx'"

And after I change python environment to 3.5, my source code can execute well.

What I have done is according to [this reference:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35484844/ptvs-how-to-reference-or-use-python-source-code-in-one-project-from-a-second-pr/35486601).
And it is actually OK when the environment is 3.5.
Is this a bug for visual studio?
Thank you :-)

Comment: I'm checking whether it is because of Anaconda

Comment: OK, I find the reason, it is necessary to set Environment such as PYTHONPATH for every python version.